# How can I disable a button thats in a different component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I have this component structure: i have a dialog which has an "add" button a rendered form from the child component(structure above)

I am trying to make the button disabled untill the child component( the form) is valid. When the form is valid; the button becomes enabled.

structure:

```
<ng-container >
  <add-action-form
    [patches]="this.config.data"
  >
  </add-action-form>

  <div class="p-dialog-footer">
    <button
      pButton
      class="p-button-secondary p-button-text"
      [label]="cancel"
      (click)="onCancel()"
    ></button>
    <button
      pButton
      [label]="add action"
      (click)="onAddAction()"
    ></button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using reactive forms you can subscribe to the value changes of the form and emit an event back stating form is valid or not.

Here is an example.

**add-action-form.component.ts**

```
// some code

form: FormGroup();

@Output()
valueChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

ngOnInit() {

  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(_ => valueChanged.emit(this.form.valid));
}

// some more code
```

```
<ng-container >
  <add-action-form
    [patches]="this.config.data"
    (valueChanged)="addActionFormValid = $event"
  >
  </add-action-form>

  <div class="p-dialog-footer">
    <button
      pButton
      class="p-button-secondary p-button-text"
      [label]="cancel"
      (click)="onCancel()"
      [disabled]="!addActionFormValid"
    ></button>
    <button
      pButton
      [label]="add action"
      (click)="onAddAction()"
      [disabled]="addActionFormValid"
    ></button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```